# Question about totally disconnected compact uniform space

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{U})$ be a compact uniform space. For $D\in\mathcal{U}$, the sequence $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$
is called a $D$- chain if $(x_i, x_{i+1})\in D$ for all $i\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $X$ be totally disconnected and $E\in\mathcal{U}$ be given. 
Is it true that

There is $D\in\mathcal{U}$ such that for every $D$- chain $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$, we have $(x_i, x_j)\in E$ for all $i, j\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Please help me to understand it.

Comment: uniform spaces are separated in this question? So the topology derived from it is $T_{3\frac12}$?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma . In my research it is important $X$ is non-metric space.

Comment: But is it Hausdorff?

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, Yes it is Hausdorff